# Petition return 404 all the time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I create my first CRUD with Springboot but I receive a **404 response** all the time.

I checked already the path, the URL and the variables name. When I run Springboot its run with no problem so I guess is connected properly but it cannot find the path.

UserModel:

```
package com.ignase.firstcrud.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

UserController:

```
package com.ignase.firstcrud.controllers;

import com.ignase.firstcrud.models.UserModel;
import com.ignase.firstcrud.services.UserService;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value ="/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @GetMapping(value ="/getUser")
    public ArrayList<UserModel> getUsers(){
        return this.userService.getUsers();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public UserModel saveUser(@RequestBody UserModel user){
        return this.userService.saveUser(user);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public Optional<UserModel> getUserById(@PathVariable ("id") Long id){
        return this.userService.getById(id);
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public UserModel updateUserById(@RequestBody UserModel request, @PathVariable("id") Long id){
        return this.userService.updateById(request, id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public String deleteById(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        boolean ok = this.userService.deleteUser(id);

        if (ok) return "user with id "+ id+ " deleted!";
        else return "Error, user not deleted";
    }

}
```

UserRepository:

```
package com.ignase.firstcrud.repositories;

import com.ignase.firstcrud.models.UserModel;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface IUserRepository extends JpaRepository <UserModel, Long> {
}
```

UserService:

```
package com.ignase.firstcrud.services;

import com.ignase.firstcrud.models.UserModel;
import com.ignase.firstcrud.repositories.IUserRepository;
import org.apache.catalina.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    IUserRepository userRepository;

    public ArrayList<UserModel> getUsers(){
        return (ArrayList<UserModel>) userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public UserModel saveUser(UserModel user){
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public Optional<UserModel> getById(Long id){
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public UserModel updateById(UserModel request, Long id){
        UserModel user = userRepository.findById(id).get();
        user.setFirstName(request.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(request.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(request.getEmail());

        return user;
    }

    public Boolean deleteUser(Long id){
        try {
            userRepository.deleteById(id);
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

FirstCrudApplication:

```
package com.ignase.firstcrud;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FirstCrudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FirstCrudApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/users
spring.datasource.username=ignacio
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

The URL that I use in the postman is `http://localhost:8888/users/getUser`

Comment: Spring Boot will start at port 8080 by default, not 8888.

Comment: OMG! what a rookie mistake, thanks so much for your comment!!